# Snowflake - Identify duplicate rows and flag them using update statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I want to identify duplicate rows of a table and add a error code to them. I want to keep one value in all cases and mark all others as duplicate. Snowflake doesn't support `CTE` & `UPDATE` statement in one query unlike SQL server. So how do i go about implementing this?

Table creation Code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DUP_CODE_TEST;
CREATE TABLE DUP_CODE_TEST
AS (

  SELECT '1' AS PARENT,'OWN' AS REL, '11' AS CHILD, 'ROW1' AS X, NULL AS ERR_CD
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1',          'OWN' AS REL, '11'         , 'ROW2'     , NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1',          'OWN' AS REL, '11'         , 'ROW3'     , NULL

);
```

Source Table:

```
+--------+-----+-------+------+--------+
| PARENT | REL | CHILD |  X   | ERR_CD |
+--------+-----+-------+------+--------+
|      1 | OWN |    11 | ROW1 | NULL   |
|      1 | OWN |    11 | ROW2 | NULL   |
|      1 | OWN |    11 | ROW3 | NULL   |
+--------+-----+-------+------+--------+
```

I would do this in SQL SERVER

```
WITH CTE_UPD 
AS 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENT,REL,CHILD ORDER BY X ) RN FROM DUP_CODE_TEST
) 
UPDATE CTE_UPD
SET ERR_CD = 'AR-DUP'
WHERE RN = 2
```

and the expected output is

```
+--------+-----+-------+------+-----------+
| PARENT | REL | CHILD |  X   |  ERR_CD   |
+--------+-----+-------+------+-----------+
|      1 | OWN |    11 | ROW1 | NULL      |
|      1 | OWN |    11 | ROW2 | DUPLICATE |
|      1 | OWN |    11 | ROW3 | DUPLICATE |
+--------+-----+-------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar -- assuming that `X` is unique:

```
UPDATE DUP_CODE_TEST t
    SET ERR_CD = 'AR-DUP'
    FROM (SELECT PARENT, REL, CHILD, MIN(X) as MIN_X
          FROM DUP_CODE_TEST tt
          GROUP BY PARENT, REL, CHILD
         ) tt
    WHERE t.PARENT = tt.PARENT AND t.REL = tt.REL AND
          t.CHILD = tt.CHILD AND tt.X > t.MIN_X;
```

That is, Snowflake does support joining to another table (or subquery).  This summarizes the table to get a minimum X for each group and then uses that for the update.

Comment: Thanks. What if X is not unique? anyway to implement that?

Comment: @venky__ . . . If the rows are complete duplicates -- that is, all columns are the same -- then this may not be possible in Snowflake.  There is no "internal id" that you can use.  However, you might be able to use another column -- or fix the table.

Comment: Yep, that is what I ended up doing. Reused a META_ROW_ID column which was just a `sequence` this made the problem trivial.